# Trouble removing pager from toolbar in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, toolbar, pager

Having trouble removing the pager from the category pages within Magento 2. I extended the catalog module and placed the removal reference inside catalog_category_view.xml. This however does not work, any help is appreciated.

```
<referenceBlock name="product_list_toolbar_pager" remove="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `default.xml` in any of your custom module with following code. It will remove pager.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product_list_toolbar_pager" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: This removes the toolbar from all pages.

Comment: How we can remove only "Limiter" from pagination pdp in magento 2?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the best solution but I copied toolbar.phtml to my module and just commented them out.

Answer (score 0):

In this answer I'm using **Magento 2.1.7**, so this answer could be modified later.
I have tried first with the layout solution using xml but without success.
[image]
I managed to remove the **pager** from the **toolbar** in **category page** by overriding the following file:

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/toolbar.phtml

To do so, inside your Theme folder  add the following folder architecture:

> Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list

Then copy/past the **toolbar.phtml** into it, you can remove the pager by commenting line number: 31 like the following:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php
/**
 * Product list toolbar
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar
 */
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\ProductList\Toolbar;
?>
<?php if ($block->getCollection()->getSize()): ?>
    <div class="toolbar toolbar-products" data-mage-init='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getWidgetOptionsJson(); ?>'>
        <?php if ($block->isExpanded()): ?>
            <?php include ($block->getTemplateFile('Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar/viewmode.phtml')) ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php  include ($block->getTemplateFile('Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar/amount.phtml')) ?>

        <?php  echo $block->getPagerHtml() ?>

        <?php  include ($block->getTemplateFile('Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar/limiter.phtml')) ?>

        <?php if ($block->isExpanded()): ?>
            <?php // include ($block->getTemplateFile('Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar/sorter.phtml')) ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif ?>
```

As you can see there is a comment in this line:

```
        <?php // include ($block->getTemplateFile('Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar/sorter.phtml')) ?>
```

After removing the cache I have now the pager removed in category page.
[image]